# Cant autoplay video in windows safari

Tags: jquery, html, video, safari, autoplay

As we know autoplaying video in mobile devices is a Tough task as video autoplay has been removed from android and ios devices to minimize data usage of the user who pay for the mobile internet in loads.
Hence, i have used jquery in order to trigger autoplay video and also have included the autoplay keyword in the video tag but anyhow it doesnt work on windows safari . Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#play').trigger('click');  

 });

function vidplay() {
   var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
   var button = document.getElementById("play");
   if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      button.textContent = "||";
   } else {
      video.pause();
      button.textContent = ">";
   }
}

function restart() {
    var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
    video.currentTime = 0;
}

function skip(value) {
    var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
    video.currentTime += value;
}
```

I have used the video tag along with autoplay and it is working fine in windows chrome but isn't working in windows safari. Here is the html part

```
<body>        

<video id="Video1" autoplay loop muted playsinline controls>

    <source src="http://sandbox399.mybigcommerce.com/content/Video/Violet_vapor_intro_3D_v2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://sandbox399.mybigcommerce.com/content/Video/Violet_vapor_intro_3D_v2.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 



</video>

<div id="buttonbar">
<button id="restart" onclick="restart();">[]</button> 
<button id="rew" onclick="skip(-10)">&lt;&lt;</button>
<button id="play" onclick="vidplay()">&gt;</button>
<button id="fastFwd" onclick="skip(10)">&gt;&gt;</button>

</div>         
</body>
```

I just want this video autoplaying in windows safari . Any kind of help will be appreciated. I tried with videojs but i don't know much about it, so just posted this here.

Comment: Apple hasn’t released safari on Windows since May 2012, almost 6 years ago.

Comment: Video tag isnt working on it eventhough this is the case